# Prepend text to a file in C

Tags: c, file, io

I want to add a standard header to a file (or group of files) using C. These files could be quite large, so it would be a bad idea to load them into memory, or copy them into temporary files (I think).

Is there a way to simply prepend the header directly to each file?

The header itself is quite small, not more than 1 KB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible without a temporary file - you can read the file from the end, block by block, writing each block back at `(original_position + header_size)`. The first block would be written back at `header_size`, leaving room for the header.

However, you don't really want to do this. It would corrupt the file if aborted (think: out of disk space, other I/O error, power down, whatever).

Thus, you should actually use temporary file - write to it everything you need, then rename it to the original file's name (assuming you create temporary file on the same file system, otherwise you'd need to copy).

**Edit:** to clarify what I mean, simplified solution when the whole file fits in RAM:

- allocate buffer same size as the file
- open the file, and read it into the buffer
- seek(file, header_size) and write the buffer here
- seek(file, 0) write the header

If the file is to big, you can allocate smaller buffer and repeat reads/writes starting with read at `file_size - buffer_size` and write at `file_size - buffer_size + header_size`. Then repeat with next chunk read at `file_size - 2 * buffer_size`, write at `file_size - 2 * buffer_size + header_size`, and so on.

But let me repeat: **you risk corrupting your file if it fails!**

Comment: Would it be possible to check if `header_size` blocks are available before the start of the file, write to them, then modify the file to incorporate the new block? Is this not similar to appending to a file?

Comment: For clarity - I didn't mean a disk block, or anything like that. I mean some portion of the file you can load to RAM at once, nothing more.

Comment: Then I have no idea how to implement your suggestion. I am not at all certain how to create an offset in a file to which something can be written, or to write a file in blocks. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: So you really want to risk loosing data? :)

Comment: It's at least interesting theoretically

Answer (score 11):

You cannot insert data into a file.

However, there is no need to load the entire file in memory. Just create a new file, write the data you are inserting, then copy the contents of the original file to the new file (do it block by block instead of loading the entire file into memory).

Finally, delete the original file and rename the new file to match the original file.

This is the way to do this and it is reasonably efficient.

Comment: In that case, how does appending to a file work? I understand appending is a trivial operation. Is it implemented as above, or does it use something fundamentally different? And how does prepending differ from appending in these respects?

Comment: When appending, the system doesn't need to move the data around. In theory, it could be possible to insert insert data at the beginning if its size is an integer multiple of file system's allocation unit, but I'm not aware of any file system API allowing it. And actually if it possible or not (even in theory) very much depends on how the file system tracks the file blocks (linked list would allow it, FAT perhaps?)

Comment: Appending simply writes to the end of the file. It is trivial. Prepending would require shifting file data around to make room for the prepended data (or restructuring the data somehow so that the new data is positioned before the existing data). That's not trivial. So the way to approach it is just as I have described.

Comment: @JonathanWood Why does prepending require shifting data around? Why can't you write the header *before* the file location on disk, then shift the pointer to the file back? I'm a bit fuzzy on how to do this, though

Comment: Because "shifting the file pointers" around like this is complex. The file allocation table will have references to the current location. Those would all need to be changed. Also, file space is allocated in fixed chunks. If you inserted data that was not exactly a multiple of the chunk size, you'd end up with gaps. Either way, it's just not supported as has been explained.

Comment: @BlackSheep - A file is not stored contiguously on disk. It is sliced in blocks which are spread on available locations. Writing at the end of file means filling the last block, then requesting a new one until the end of appended data. Writing before the start would involve the request of a new block and filling it halfway starting from its end. I know no filesystem able to do that.

Comment: Suggest rather than "delete the original file and rename the new file", to rename original, rename new to original and then delete the renamed original.  This exercises renaming ability (program has that privileged) before file deletion.  Other approaches possible.  Overall, this answers approach is good.