# Is it possible to allocate a single byte of memory at a specific address?

Tags: c, memory-management

Is it possible to allocate a single byte of memory at a specific desired address, say `0x123`?

This suggests follow up questions:
Is it possible to know if a specific address has already been `malloc`ed?

Some complications could be:

1. The byte at the desired address `0x123` was already `malloc`'ed. In this case, can I move the byte value elsewhere and notify the compiler (or whatever's keeping track of these things) of the new address of the byte?
2. The byte at the desired address `0x123` was `malloc`'ed along with other bytes. E.g. `char *str = malloc(8);` and `str` <= `0x123` < `str + 8`, or in other words, `0x123` overlaps some portion of already `malloc`'ed memory. In this case, is it possible to move the portion of `malloc`'ed memory elsewhere and notify the compiler (or whatever's keeping track of these things)?

There are also several variations:

1. Is this possible if the desired address is known at compile time?
2. Is this possible if the desired address is known at run time?

I know `mmap` takes a hint `addr`, but it allocates in multiples of the pagesize and may or may not allocate at the given hint `addr`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are several related questions, which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=malloc%20at%20specific%20address), but it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. If you want to actually allocate an exact address, that is unlikely to work reliably or at all. Can you explain more about what the _goal_ is? Why do you need to allocate an exact address? A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the best way to ensure that you'll get the help you need.

Comment: Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: No, that's not how memory allocation works.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin and @bnaecker!!! Since this question/post already has answers, should I clarify in a different question/post. This describes the _actual problem_: https://repl.it/@joseville/prependbyte#main.c.

In summary, I would like to load a file into memory and prepend a single byte (a `\n` in this case) because this would simplify subsequent logic. I found this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384968/prepend-text-to-a-file-in-c).

Comment: That case is covered by @user253751's answer. Essentially you want to use a buffer (or mapped memory region) and set the first byte to `'\n'` and then read the file into the space after that. You can simply `malloc` a buffer of `filesize + 2`, set the 1st byte to `'\n'`, read the file into the rest with `fread` and use a trick of setting the last byte to `0` (the *nul-character*) so you can treat the entire thing as a string.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin. I was able to do this with `malloc` and `mmap`. I `malloc`'ed a big enough memory region s.t. the `malloc`'ed memory region is guaranteed to have an address `addr` that is page aligned and meets a few other requirements, so that I can feed `addr` into `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` and then do `*addr - 1 = '\n'`. The details are all here: https://repl.it/@joseville/prependbyte#mmap_a_malloc.c. It might be more complicated than it's worth.

I think depending on the value of `fsize` it might be more efficient to use `fread` instead of `mmap`.

Comment: Note: The code I linked (repl.it/@joseville/prependbyte#mmap_a_malloc.c) only worked for a toy example.

Comment: Great job and good initiative working though the suggestion here and from the answer to answer your question. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are operating-system-specific ways to do this. On Windows, you can use [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) (with the `MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE` flags). On Linux, you can use [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (with the `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` flag). These are the operating system functions which give you full control over your own address space.

In either case, you can only map entire pages. Addresses only become valid and invalid a page at a time. You can't have a page that is only half valid, and you can't have a page where only one address is valid. This is a CPU limitation.

If the page you want is already allocated, then obviously you can't allocate it again.

On both Windows and Linux, you can't allocate the first page. This is so that accesses to NULL pointers (which point to the first page) will always crash.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to assign a specific value to a pointer as follows:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)0x123;
```

However dereferencing such a pointer will almost certainly result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on any hosted system.

The only time such a construct would be valid is on an embedded system where it is allowed to access an arbitrary address and the implementation documents specific addresses for specific uses.

As for trying to manipulate the inner workings of a `malloc` implementation, such a task is very system specific and not likely to yield any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to allocate a single byte of memory at a specific desired address, say 0x123?

Generally: no. The C language doesn't cover allocation at specific addresses, it only covers how to access a specific address. Many compilers do provide a non-standard language extensions for how to allocate at a fixed address. When sticking to standard C, the actual allocation must either be done:

- In hardware, by for example having a MCU which provides a memory-mapped register map, or
- By the system-specific linker, through custom linker scripts.

See [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276290) for details.

`malloc` doesn't make any sense in either case, since it exclusively uses heap allocation and the heap sits inside a pre-designated address space.